# Table with Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a form using a table. I have a total of 7 fields. What I am hoping to accomplish is have 3 fields on one row, 3 fields on the second row and the last row would be the last field extended. I tried using colspan however the editorfor box for NextAction is not extending all the way. There is a margin on the right hand side of this field. I've tried creating a CSS class to take away the margin however that did not work as well.

How can I get it so that the NextAction field extends all the way to the last column?

Below I've added my code for the last 2 rows of my table.

```
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label labelpadding" })
                </td>
                <td style="width:300px">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Principal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                </td>
                <td style="width:300px">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Principal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Principal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label labelpadding" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label labelpadding" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, new SelectList(ViewBag.Status, "Status", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label labelpadding" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FollowUpDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label labelpadding" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FollowUpDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NextAction, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label labelpadding" })
                </td>
                <td colspan="5">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NextAction, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ", @style = "margin-right: 0 !important;"} })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NextAction, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

[image: This is what I see]

Comment: can you post the full code?

Comment: I edited my code. There's the full code for my table.

Comment: It looks like you're using bootstrap. Why use an HTML table and not Bootstrap's CSS classes? Can you confirm if you're using Bootstrap?

Comment: Originally I was using bootstrap but the columns were getting all messed up so I went with HTML instead since I understand it more.

Comment: you have to colspan all other cells to and make your table bigger. now the table width is 3 and you want to make 5 this is not possible

Comment: Right now the table width is 6 columns. Each label has it's own column and each input box has its own column. For my last row I want the label to be 1 col and the input to be 5 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have Bootstrap enabled on your project, use Bootstrap's CSS class `w-100`. This class will make an element it is applied to have have 100% width. Here is the updated `EditorFor` line with that class added:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NextAction, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control w-100"} })
```

If that doesn't work, you likely have something else overriding it. Check your other style sheets and the HTML that is rendered in your browser.

Comment: @user9448003 If I answered your question, please consider choosing my answer as "Best Answer". Thanks!